# Formula to check if string is empty in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have written a formula to return a string based on logic run on a string field in my database.  I have everything working, except I'm unable to return when the field is the empty string.

This is what I need:

```
...
else if ({TABLE.FIELD} = "") then
    "Fixed"
...
```

However, this entry appears as the empty string in my report.  I've tried testing the length of the field to 0 and the StrCmp functions.  Nothing seems to work.  Google results state that a simple comparison to "" or '' should make the logic work.  I am new to CR, so maybe I am missing something.  Any ideas on how I can acquire this functionality?

Comment: `However, this entry appears as the empty string in my report.`  What exactly is getting shown?  It's not clear from your description.

Comment: The empty string is being printed / returned.  All other fields display the correct string (ie Fixed).

Comment: It's been a long while since I used Crystal, but are you sure it's actually empty and not `null`?  If I recall correctly, Crystal does a very poor job of handling null values, and they must be checked first; check to see if the string is a null as your very first test and display "Fixed", see if that clears things up.

Comment: I did have a null check, but it was not the first piece of logic.  Moving it to the beginning made it work.  Make an answer, and I'll accept it. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad it worked!  I've got plenty of rep, if @Andrew's answer worked, feel free to accept his answer since it will be more visible than my comment.

Comment: NVL function would be nice instead of this IF-THEN mess.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can check for IsNull condition.

```
If IsNull({TABLE.FIELD}) or {TABLE.FIELD} = "" then
  // do something
```

Comment: Although it should be obvious from the answer, you want to check for `NULL` as your first check, since Crystal Reports is picky about handling nulls.

Comment: in "//do something" i want to set certain text but its always returning false instead of the text

Comment: @numerah `If IsNull({Table.Field}) = True Then // do something` or if you just want two parts (true or false), you can try the IIF function (expression, TruePart, falsePart) ... The If-Then also has an Else component this makes it complicated to use if you just need a true & false parts.

Answer (score 4):

On the formula menu just Select "Default Values for Nulls" then just add all the fields like the below:

```
{@Table.Field1} + {@Table.Field2} + {@Table.Field3} + {@Table.Field4} + {@Table.Field5}
```

Comment: Thank you sir you saved my time, just Select "Default Values for Nulls"

Answer (score 1):

```
if {le_gur_bond.gur1}="" or IsNull({le_gur_bond.gur1})   Then
    ""
else 
 "and " + {le_gur_bond.gur2} + " of "+ {le_gur_bond.grr_2_address2}
```

Comment: Please don't post code only answers. Go ahead and add an explaination. :-)

Answer (score -1):

If IsNull({TABLE.FIELD1}) then
   "NULL" +',' + {TABLE.FIELD2}
else
  {TABLE.FIELD1} + ', ' + {TABLE.FIELD2}

Here I put NULL as string to display the string value NULL in place of the null value in the data field.
Hope you understand.